# how do you stop the typescript from copying the src folder

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I didn't change anything in tsconfig or in the folders, simply typescript wanted to start copying the entire src folder instead of just copying the files inside the src.
I tried to do it in several ways but it seems that he insists on copying the src folder while the json file is outside the src.
If I put the json file into the src it copies the json and the files into the src folder, but does not copy the folder.
But I don't want him to copy the json, I want him to be out of the src.
how I do?

[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEfCK.png)

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,      
    "resolveJsonModule": true,             /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "./dist",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./src/",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./src/",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,      /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you compile your TS into JS and the src file you are compiling from requires a package from outside of the src file then TS will nest the JS in a src file within your build or in your case dist file. Your resolveJsonModules has fixed it as that will have been the the import that caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my mistake, it was the option `resolveJsonModule` that made all this problem, typescript started copying the json files, and I still don't know why, but with this option turned on, it copied the entire src folder

Comment: That is not the reason.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes, it's

Comment: Just re-read your original question And this answer. Clearly the issue was Importing files from outside the source directory . It doesn't matter if those files are Json or not . It matters where they are located . In this case The only file you were importing What is a Json file so that the answer is completely wrong . -1.

Comment: @AluanHaddad friend, the real problem was that the src folder was being copied in its entirety along with the json file, instead of just copying the .ts files and turning them into .js.
And this problem only passed if I put the json inside the src folder, then it only copied the files. But he still copied the json, and I didn't want him to do that.
when I disabled `` resolveJsonModule``` he stopped trying to copy json.

Comment: @AluanHaddad you need to reread the question, the problem has always been to copy the entire src folder and place it in the dist, instead of just placing the files, the other problem that I specified more towards the end is that I also did not want the json to be copied.
although, in some points I think the translator must have made understanding a little strange, I'm sorry for the bad English, I don't really speak English

Comment: So you asked one question about two problems and answered in terms of one without explaining. There's a broader point here about the scope of input files usually controlled via `rootDir`. Trying to import via a relative path from a the parent directory of `src` is going to cause such problems. This is a complicated issue that a lot of people run into and, as your above comment correctly points out, it is not simply a function of `--resolveJsonModule`.